# Keep header in fixed position? How

Tags: css, position

For [this site](http://dev.missionmedia.net/justkidsmaryland/#justkidsreport), when I add fixed: position to #header it pushes the header graphic to the left.

Any suggestions on how to make the full header and it's #head property to remain fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not being "pushed" to the left, that's where the anchor is. By just adding `position: fixed` and not the `top` and `left` attributes, it will default to the `0,0` coordinates. Just set the `top` and `left` to your fitting.

### Edit

Upon looking at your code, you can actually just set `width: 100%` to a css rule that `#header` will match.

Comment: The latter is preferably, but he'll need to add padding to #main to account for the height of the #header as well since it will be out of flow.

Comment: hi thnx adding width: 100% did the trick thanks. I then added padding as well as margin to the header but did not push anything down.  So i added such to the left nav and right content area; margin-top to push those elements down.  Though what were trying to do is keep header and left nav fixed; click nav titles to smooth scroll to each subject matter.  Ironically it only works perfectly in IE7 .. any suggestions?

Comment: The smooth scrolling aspect works for me in Chrome. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Its a bit jumbled.  Ironically it works the best in IE7.  How to get it to work like that in all browsers? thnx

Comment: IT works fine for me in FF on Mac as well... what do you mean its "jumbled"?